# Can you convert a php file/page into a regular/standard URL

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

I have a php file/page that renders in a Chrome browser as I would like, but it is not a recognized as a valid URL address when putting it into a MailChimp Campaign Template wizard...I'm assuming because it ends in .php.

Is there an easy way to convert the php file into a "regular" URL?

As you can tell I don't have a technical background.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a folder on your server, copy that php page to that folder and rename it to index.php

at the moment it might look like:

```
http://www.stackoverflow/wizard/test.php
```

After you create the folder and rename the php file it will be:

```
http://www.stackoverflow/wizard/
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the problem is the php page returns a 404 error in an online CURL, although it renders completely fine in the browser correctly.  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 00:16:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" .... Not sure why? Any one have any ideas. I saw similar postings about this, but didn't understand the solution.